# Deserialize JSON to c# dictionary // Problem with structure

Tags: c#, json, json-deserialization

I want to deserialize JSON that looks like this:

```
{
    "rooms":{
        "room1":{
            "id":"bPhJoQTTE",
            "roomName":"room1"
        },
         "room2":{
            "id":"bPh1oqLTE",
            "roomName":"room2"
        }
    }
}
```

I'm using the following class definitions for deserialization:

```
public class Room
{
    public string id;
    public string roomName;
}

public class Rooms
{
    public Dictionary<string, Room> room;
}

public class Root
{
    public Rooms rooms;
}
```

And here's the code I'm using to perform the deserialization:

```
Root deserializationObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(json);
```

It's not working - what am I doing wrong?

Comment: `rooms` already represents `Dictionary<string, Room>` structure

Comment: You can use https://json2csharp.com/ to generate the data structure you'd need for a valid json

Comment: See my answer for your current json format. Also, the "roomName" member of Room" is redundant because each key in the dictionary is already the room name. I.e., Depending upon how you would like to use the data, you can change both your json and the C# classes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't need the `Rooms` class at all. Try updating `Root` to look like this:

```cs
public class Root
{
    public Dictionary<string, Room> rooms;
}
```

Also, your `Room` class has a `username` property that isn't in your example JSON, and it's missing the `roomName` property from your example.

Answer (score 0):

```
public sealed record TestData(Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>> rooms);

public class TestJson
{
    public static void Test()
    {
        const string JsonData = "{ \"rooms\" : { " +
            "\"room1\" : {\"id\" : \"bPhJoQTTE\", \"roomName\" : \"room1\"}," +
            "\"room2\" : {\"id\" : \"bPh1oqLTE\", \"roomName\" : \"room2\"}" +
            "}}";

        var obj = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<TestData>(JsonData);

        // or simply

        const string JsonData2 = "{ " +
            "\"room1\" : {\"id\" : \"bPhJoQTTE\", \"roomName\" : \"room1\"}," +
            "\"room2\" : {\"id\" : \"bPh1oqLTE\", \"roomName\" : \"room2\"}" +
            "}";

        var obj2 = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>>>(JsonData2);
    }
}
```